# Is there a better way to run this function on two separate elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I have a function which sums the numbers of an input field down to a single digit.

I have two separate input fields, which will both take different data. I want to run the function on both, when the HTML button(with onClick) is clicked.

I couldnt figure out a way to do this, without creating a duplicate function. I know theres a better way, can anyone give me an idea?

```
function getSum1() {
const input = document.getElementById('dateInput1').value;
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    const num = parseInt(input.charAt(i));
    if (!isNaN(num)) {
        sum += num;
         }
    }
  const total = (sum - 1) % 9 + 1;
    document.getElementById("result1").textContent = "Your number is: " + total;
}
function getSum2() {
const input = document.getElementById('dateInput2').value;
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    const num = parseInt(input.charAt(i));
    if (!isNaN(num)) {
        sum += num;
         }
    }
  const total = (sum - 1) % 9 + 1;
    document.getElementById("result2").textContent = "Your number is: " + total;
}
```

---

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="cell-1"><input type="text" id="dateInput1"></div>
        <div class="cell-2"><img src="file:///Users/Nineborn/Downloads/My%20Post.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="cell-3"><input type="text" id="dateInput2"></div>
        <div class="cell-4" id="result1"></div>
        <div class="cell-5"><button onclick="getSum1(); getSum2()">Calculate</button></div>
        <div class="cell-6" id="result2"></div>
        <div class="cell-7"></div>
        <div class="cell-8"></div>
        <div class="cell-9"></div>


    </div>
```

Comment: When determining how to reduce duplicate code, the first step is always to compare the two functions and determine what's the same, and what's different. As far as I can tell, your functions are identical, except for one single string: `"result1"` and `"result2"`. Take out everything elseand make it a common function, then pass the element id as an argument. Then you could do `getSum("result1")` and `getSum("result2")`.

Comment: That exactly my problem though. Originally it was one function.. they are identical. And i couldn't figure out how to run the function on both input fields, AND return the separate values, each on their own element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you place the `id`s of the input and output elements into arrays and then loop over the input array, you can perform the main operation as many times as there items in the array.

```js
function getSum() {
  // Place the id's of the input and output elements into respective arrays
  let inputs = ['dateInput1','dateInput2'];
  let outputs = ['result1','result2'];
  
  // Loop over the items in the inputs array
  // This will cause you to loop as many times as there are input elements
  inputs.forEach(function(input, index){

    // Instead of hard-coding the element id, you get the element reference
    // from the .forEach callback function argument.
    const inputValue = document.getElementById(input).value;
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < inputValue.length; i++) {
      const num = parseInt(inputValue.charAt(i));
      if (!isNaN(num)) {
        sum += num;
      }
    }
    const total = (sum - 1) % 9 + 1;
    // And here, you reference the right output element, by using the corresponding
    // index from the inputs array.
    document.getElementById(outputs[index]).textContent = "Your number is: " + total;
  
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="cell-1"><input type="text" id="dateInput1"></div>
        <div class="cell-2"><img src="file:///Users/Nineborn/Downloads/My%20Post.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="cell-3"><input type="text" id="dateInput2"></div>
        <div class="cell-4" id="result1"></div>
        <div class="cell-5"><button onclick="getSum();">Calculate</button></div>
        <div class="cell-6" id="result2"></div>
        <div class="cell-7"></div>
        <div class="cell-8"></div>
        <div class="cell-9"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks this is good, havent tried it yet. Im fairly new but i get the gist of your code. Could you explain the arguments (input, index) on the forEach function? Thats the part i'm not fully understanding.

Comment: @nineborn [The `.forEach()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) requires that you pass it a function that will be invoked for each array item. That function will automatically be passed 3 arguments: a reference to the array item being iterated, the index number of the current item being iterated, and a reference to the entire array. You only have to set up arguments to receive these parameters and can give them any syntaxually valid name you like, they get passed to your function automatically.

Comment: ok so you are making a placeholder name (input, index), and referencing each array in the DOM and extracting its value with "const inputValue = document.getElementById(input).value;"

correct?

Comment: @nineborn Correct!

Comment: thanks it works great. I dont know if I can switch topics here, but when i originally wrote the logic to get that sum of the input field, i was using and input "date" form. I decided i didnt like it, so i changed it to a simple text input. Is all the parsing and logic in my GetSum function still necessary? I think it was necessary because there were "/" characters in the date input form, and so i had to run !NaN.

Comment: in other words, is there a simpler way

Comment: @nineborn You'll have to explain exactly what you are trying to do and what the expected input into these fields would be.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this off of the digits of an `int` will make it so you can do this the same for both

```
function getSum(number) {
  var sum = 0;
  while (number > 0) {
    sum+=number %10;
    number /= 10;
  }
}
```

Then, all you need to do is

```
var num = document.getElementById('dateInput1').value;
num = getSum(parseInt(num));
document.getElementById("result1").textContent = "Your number is: " + num;
```

Answer (score 0):

the `n` will be the number that you have in the `ID`/`Class`:

```
function getSum(n) {
const input = document.getElementById('dateInput' + n).value;
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    const num = parseInt(input.charAt(i));
    if (!isNaN(num)) {
        sum += num;
         }
    }
  const total = (sum - 1) % 9 + 1;
    document.getElementById("result" + n).textContent = "Your number is: " + total;
}
```

or you can use this if the divs class names are different (`n1` or the input `id`, `n2` is for the result `id`):

```
function getSum(n1, n2) {
const input = document.getElementById(n1).value;
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    const num = parseInt(input.charAt(i));
    if (!isNaN(num)) {
        sum += num;
         }
    }
  const total = (sum - 1) % 9 + 1;
    document.getElementById(n2).textContent = "Your number is: " + total;
}
```

Comment: i dont really understand whats happening here

Comment: i think we may be mixed up, or maybe im not reading it properly.The document where i change the text content is the element which displays the summed number. There are two elements (the input forms) that i want to target with this function. So i would have to have two separate id tags, or a class which i tried but the whole thing wouldnt run.

Comment: Can you include the changes you'd make the the HTML?